# Dart Flutter : Why Android studio Emulator has no Gallery?

Tags: android-studio-3.0

Android studio Emulator has no Gallery among the apps. Is there anyway to get the emulator to show the gallery, which is present by default on all android phones?

Dart/Flutter needs to access it with the Image_Picker library.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "stock" gallery app from google was discontinued with Lollipop. Now each manufacturer or ROM developer can decide wether they implement their own Gallery App or use Google Photos. 
The Android Studio Stock emulator ROM with Google Features uses the Google Photos app as a gallery.

You could download another Gallery app and install it on your emulator if you like but it would be pretty much the same.

[Here](https://m.androidcentral.com/where-did-gallery-go-after-lollipop-update) is an article about why Google removed the Stock Gallery App in Lollipop.

The package [image_picker](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_picker) handles this part on its own.

Comment: Thank you. It works. I was concerned because image_picker takes a parameter gallery as in: ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery); But as you said it accesses Photos which is what I was looking for. Thanks.